# Select Related Dropdown Value Convert and Submit

Tags: jquery, sql-server, sql-server-2008, coldfusion

**Background** 
 
Running ColdFusion 9 with SQL Server 2008 r2 
I am using a 3 level chained dropdown/related select with jquery for relation. 
This Example http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained

In order for them to be linked they rely on id which is an int.

The Option **Values** are coming from a database.

```
<select name="brand" id="brand">
<option value="1">Apple</option>
<option value="2">Samsung</option>
</select>  

<select name="device" id="device">
<option value="1" class="apple">iPhone5s</option>
<option value="1" class="apple">iPhon4s</option
</select>  

<select name="os" id="os">
<option value="1" class="apple">iOS5</option>
<option value="1" class="apple">iPhon4s</option>
</select>
```

And the Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#device").chained("#brand");
    $("#os").chained("#device");
  });
</script>
```

All this is working

When I submit this I get only id values which for example are 
*The Numbers are the actual value* 
brand: 1 
device: 1  
os: 1

**Now the Question** 
when I submit the form i am running a select statement first to get the text values for the relevant id. Then inserting the values converted values on the same page.

Now all this is working. My only concern is will there be any issues using this method?
And is there any other method for achieving this?

SQL Script for getting values

```
  select distinct brand_list, brand_id
  from 
  where brand_id = '#form.brand#'
  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';
```

Is waitfor delay even needed. The only reason i put it there cuz I want this query to finish first before inserting anything

SQL Script for Submitting Values

```
 insert into forms (brands) Values (brand_list)
```

Comment: If you have them both running on the same page the insert won't execute before the code before it has completed

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the dropdown is setup correctly to work with this jquery method.  I believe it should look like this, using the same JQuery lines:

```
<select name="brand" id="brand">
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
</select>  

<select name="device" id="device">
    <option value="iPhone5S" class="Apple">iPhone 5S</option>
    <option value="iPhone4S" class="Apple">iPhone 4S</option
</select>  

<select name="os" id="os">
    <option value="iOS7" class="Apple iPhone5S">iOS 7</option>
    <option value="iOS5" class="Apple iPhone4S">iOS 5</option>
</select>
```

If you want to integrate that with a ColdFusion query, you can change it to:

```
<CFQUERY name="qryBrands" datasource="myDS">
    SELECT brand_key, brand_description, class_list FROM BRAND_TABLE
</CFQUERY>
<CFQUERY name="qryDevices" datasource="myDS">
    SELECT device_key, device_description, class_list FROM DEVICE_TABLE
</CFQUERY>
<CFQUERY name="qryOS" datasource="myDS">
    SELECT os_key, os_description, class_list FROM OS_TABLE
</CFQUERY>


<select name="brand" id="brand">
    <option value="-" class=""> Select a brand </option>
    <CFOUTPUT query="qryBrands">
        <option value="#brand_key#" class="#class_list#">#brand_description#</option>
    </CFOUTPUT>
</select>  

<select name="device" id="device">
    <option value="-" class=""> Select a device </option>
    <CFOUTPUT query="qryDevices">
        <option value="#device_key#" class="#class_list#">#device_description#</option>
    </CFOUTPUT>
</select>  

<select name="os" id="os">
    <option value="-" class=""> Select an OS </option>
    <CFOUTPUT query="qryOS">
        <option value="#os_key#" class="#class_list#">#os_description#</option>
    </CFOUTPUT>
</select>
```

Obviously, this can be customized and streamlined, but it gets you started.